# Website hangs after drop down post back

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, session

I have a website installed on one of our sales guys laptops and am having issues with the website hanging if left for 2 minutes. This doesn't happen on my dev box, my live machine or the other sales guys machine.

The website will hang. It's not just limited to this page, it will happen on all pages when I leave it for more than 2 minutes and then try and process a page that calls back via  button or drop down ect. I have checked the IIS settings of the machine and everything seems the same as the other sales guys machine who is running the same version of the site.

Here are the specs:
Dev Box: asp.net 2, windows server 2008 64bit

Live Box: asp.net 2, windows server 2008 64bit

Working Sales Guy: asp.net2 windows 7 64bit

Broken Sales Guy: asp.net 2 Windows vista 32 bit (the only thing I can see different is windows version)

Would appreciate some input on this if possible, many thanks.

EDIT: For more information, if I stop the website from trying to load while it hangs, clear my history for the last hour and then refresh, the page comes back fine.

EDIT2: I have just spat out some debug information and it seems it doesn't even go into the post back I need.

EDIT3: This doesn't seem to happen when using Chrome but does when using IE and Mozilla.

Comment: What version of IE? 
What version of Mozilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Google Chrome doesn't have this issue ... the sales guy just got upgraded :)

AS this is only happening on his machine, this is a viable work around for me.